# Should a question on Git be off topic on stackoverflow?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, close-reasons

I was facing an issue with git while working with android source and asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6295884/error-syncing-with-cyanogenmod-repo) question. 
It was closed as off topic within a short time. Now I have found the solution and can't even answer my own question so that it helps some one else; as it is closed!
(I added the answer as a comment for now)

Comment: In any case, don't post an answer as a comment just because the question is closed. That's just like people that post comments as answers because they don't have enough rep -- post stuff where it belongs. If you can't, there's a reason

Comment: When the question is closed and you want to share the solution, there is no other option available to you except for the comments section(and meta, as I have realized now)

Comment: Git off topic on stackoverflow ? This question has been well covered by MichaelT. see: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6311/where-does-my-git-question-go

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Reopened.  I think git falls squarely in the "software tools commonly used by programmers" category mentioned in the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: And it's not exactly [the first time](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/git) a git question has been asked

Comment: Thanks Bill! @Michael I was surprised when the question was closed so soon as off topic. I think the people closed it was not familiar with git and repo. We should probably have a rule to say that you must have at-least answered a question with a similar tag before you can vote to close a question.