# Should this question about git/github have been closed?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, closed-questions, off-topic

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9361502/how-to-import-a-bitbucket-project-into-github-on-windows) about importing a Mercurial Bitbucket repo into Github was closed as off-topic.  I'm not sure how this substantively differs from [this Meta question on Git](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94667/should-a-question-on-git-be-off-topic-on-stackoverflow).  It seems pretty firmly in the "programming-tools" bucket.  Is this sort of question actually off-topic?

Comment: Related else-meta (P.SE): [Where does my git question go?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6311/where-does-my-git-question-go) That said, it should be a dup (as mentioned in the OP's self accepted answer) of an open question.

Comment: @MichaelT, agreed it's a dup.  It'd be nice if the question were closed for that reason instead, though not sure if that sort of power is in the hands of moderators.

Comment: Yes, we can do that. I reopened the question and closed it as a duplicate of the question linked in the accepted answer.

Comment: One of the things that could have helped (one of those "why would I do that?" but this *is* the case), if the OP had cast a close vote on their own question as a dup.  Its a privilege you get at [250 rep](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes)  That said, if you don't have the rep to cast *normal* close votes, you don't always see that link and think "I should do this."  (example of self close vote duping - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/201657/ )